# Show all time stamps for a date in a list box

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have data entered in a table multiple times a day with a date stamp and a time stamp, along with other info. I have 2 fields to filter, primary is day and the other is time. I also have a form with 2 listboxs, the one i want to show the dates and no duplicates. The other i want to display all the time stamps under that day after a day is slected from the first listbox. How do i do this in access? Is it the same as vba in excel or sql?

The following Code runs but doesnt do anything:

```
Private Sub ltbDates_Click()

[ltbFiltered].RowSourceType = "Table/Query"

[ltbFiltered].RowSource = "SELECT Time_Stamp, Layer, Status, Weight, CDI FROM Scale Weight Log " & _

                      "WHERE Date_Stamp = '" & ltbDates.Value & "'"

End Sub
```

Comment: have tried any code..

Comment: Is it vba code? Thats what im asking. I found the answer to the first part, remove duplicates, which was just in the property settings.

Comment: HA560 is requesting that you post the code you have so far, and any that you tried but didn't work correctly (and why). What are the row sources for the two listboxes? Have you attempted any VBA yet? It will likely be required to update Listbox2.

Comment: Updated with code i found online and tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

Created a query named filtered.

```
 SELECT Log.[Time Stamp] AS Expr1, Log.Status, Log.[Layer Count] AS Expr2, Log.[Part Count] AS Expr3, Log.Weight

 FROM Log

 WHERE ((([Log].[Date Stamp])=[Forms]![Scale_Weight_Log]![LtbDateStamp]))

 ORDER BY Log.[Time Stamp];
```

Then in vba

```
 Private Sub LtbDateStamp_Click()

 ltbFiltered.Requery

 End Sub
```